# Self referencing timer /uncollectable object

Tags: c#

I have a type that contains a timer which fires an instance method every 2 seconds. My problem is that when the object instance drops out of scope the object is not collected because the timer thread maintains a reference.

My question is; Is it possible to determine, at runtime, how many references a object has and if the reference count is 1 is that reference a circular reference to the same object? Basically I was thinking of adding code to the timer call back to stop the timer and set the stack reference to null if the object only has 1 circular reference.

Thanks

```
public class TypeWithSelfRefresh<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _cache = new List<T>();
    private Timer _refreshTimer;

    public TypeWithSelfRefresh()
    {
        _refreshTimer = new Timer(delegate { ClearCache();},null,2000,2000);
    }

    public void ClearCache()
    {
        lock (_cache)
        {
            _cache.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (_cache)
        {
            _cache.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
    {
        lock (_cache)
        {
            foreach (T item in _cache)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with circular references. .NET framework handles that just fine. The problem is that you are dealing with an object that implements Dispose for a reason (Timer) without disposing of it properly.

The reason any timer has to implement Dispose is simple. For it work, it has to give away a reference of itself to the underlying mechanism running the timer in the background. And that is a reference you have no direct control over. To get rid of that reference you have to call Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

The circular reference shouldn't prevent the object from being collected by the GC, because it is not reachable. What makes you think it isn't collected ? Did you call `GC.Collect` ?

Comment: I know the instances aren't collected because i can see them in the profiler (.Net Memeory Profiler).

I would never call GC.Collect ;-)

Comment: OK, but the object won't be collected as soon as it gets out of scope anyway... There is no way to know for sure when the GC will collect it. Perhaps it will be collected if the memory usage reaches a certain threshold

Comment: I can see the GC collecting all gens in the profiler .... and the instances are still alive. In the profiler I can see the timer holding the ref